# xml to json conversion and vice versa angular 4

Tags: javascript, json, angular, object

I am working in a angular 4 project and i have to convert xml to json and vice versa.
I am successfull in achieving this by using below thread:
https://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/

This is my sample xml :

```
 <food><pizza type="cheese"/></food>
```

The parser converted it to json as below:

```
{
"food":{
 "pizza":{"@type":"cheese"},
```

I have to write a selector where i need to render value of @type.
I have tried it like below:

//selector which returns @type

```
   export const foodValueSelctr= 
   createSelector(paredJsonSelectore,
       (json) => {
          console.log(json.food.pizza.@type);
          return json.food.pizza.@type;
    });
```

At this line of code I get below error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:38)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

How can I access this @type in code using dot notation ?
Also,
Can i use any other lib to achieve my functionality ?

Comment: can you try `pizza["@type"]` instead?

Comment: @ADyson perfect thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the alternative syntax (known as "bracket notation") as follows:

```
console.log(json.food.pizza["@type"]);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors for documentation.